# Do not translate specific elements with DeepL and DeepL WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, deepl

I want to translate all text, except those contained inside of specific elements, for example:

```
Please open the page <x>Settings</x> to configure your system.
```

DeepL should translate everything except for items inside the `<x>` element. I read the doc here, https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/handling-xml/ignored-tags/ and have tried looking, but can not seem to find the proper hook to add that ignore_tags parameter.

I played around with the `$this->request['ignore_tags']`, for `DeepLApiTranslate` but I would rather not edit the plugin directly.

How should I handle this / any hook I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress DeepL plugin utilises `wp_remote_*` function to send requests to their APIs so you can hook into `http_request_args` filter to add the additional argument.

Here is an example:

```
add_filter(
        'http_request_args',
        static function ( array $parse_args, string $url ): array {

            $method = $parse_args['method'] ?? '';

            if ( $method === 'POST' && str_starts_with( $url, 'https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate' ) ) {

                $body = (string) ( $parse_args['body'] ?? '' );
                parse_str( $body, $results );

                $results['ignore_tags'] = 'x';
                $parse_args['body'] = http_build_query( $results );
            }

            return $parse_args;
        },
        10,
        2
    );
```

Note that the code assumes that your site is running on PHP8 as it's using the `str_starts_with` to ensure that it filters the request arguments only when it is sending request to DeepL API endpoint.

Comment: Ah okay, cool. So the `http_request_args` filter. Nice. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to add this to my answer. Ideally you will need to add the code as a plugin, or mu-plugin. But I think adding the code to the theme `functions.php` should probably work as well.